# How to create files inside a systemd unit's private tmp dir?

Tags: systemd

For one service I need a couple directories available inside `/tmp`. But I also want to use systemd's `PrivateTmp=yes`. Is there something like `AssertPathExists=/tmp/x` that also creates the path?

edit: some more clarity

systemd's privateTmp creates a blank `/tmp` every time the process starts.

Some processes need directories that can be in `/tmp` but the configuration should point to existing ones, and the process will not create them to avoid assuming (wrongly) ownership/permissions/etc.

for example, you might have a httpd server which the config file requires you to point to a 'session storage dir', which you may want to place in `/tmp`. But if your configuration says `/tmp/httpd-session` then startup will fail, because `/tmp` was just created empty before the process starts.

Answer (score 0):

my current solution

```
[service]
...
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -g daemonuser -m 0770 -d /tmp/a /tmp/b
```

edit: explaining the above:

this is a part of my [systemd unit file](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html).

since we want it managed by systemd, so we can use privateTmp and other features, it is setup as a [Service](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#), which have it's options defined afther the `[service]` sub header. you should assume there is also a `PrivateTmp=yes` somewhere under `[Service]` as that was a requirement on the question.

Now, the main part of a service is what process should be managed (i.e. started and monitored by systemd). That is the `ExecStartPre` line, not shown.

My solution is to use the `ExecStartPre` which is executed (but not monitored, only for failure i think) before the actual `ExecStart`.

Here i use `ExecStartPre` to call [`install`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/install.1) to place all the directories i want, with the correct ownership and permissions, inside the newly created `/tmp`

The syntax for `installs` used above will create directories (as forced by the `-d` option) named: `/tmp/a` and `/tmp/b`. Owned by daemonuser, with permissions `0770`.

if you want to get fancier, you can make sure tmpDir is being setup correctly and not being litered by other unit files via namespace sharing by using something like `ConditionPathExists=!/tmp/a` which will cause systemd to fail even before the ExecStartPre if the directory already exist for some reason.

Comment: Could you please explain why you choose this solution and where goes the private directories?